# Solving two linear equations with one variable

Tags: r

I have the following problem:
I would like to write a function that calculates the break even point and plots the two linear equations.
The function I wrote so far works with a while loop and is able to calculate the break even point for an even amount. Here is the function:

```
bep <- function(Kf,kv,p){
    x <- 1
    K <- Kf + kv * x
    U <- p * x
    while(K != U){
            x <- x + 1
            K <- Kf + kv * x
            U <- p * x
            print(x)
    }
    bep <- x
    print(bep)
    print(p*bep)
    x <- seq(0, 100, by=10)
    K <- Kf + kv * x
    U <- p * x
    plot(x, K, type="l", col="red", ylim=c(0,20000))
    lines(x, U, col="green")
    points(bep, Kf+kv*bep)
    segments(x0 = 0, y0 = p * bep, x1 = bep, y1= p * bep, lty = "dotted")
    segments(x0 = bep, y0 = 0, x1 = bep, y1 = p * bep, lty = "dotted")
}
```

The arguments are Kf for my fixed cost, kv for variable cost and p for price.
When I test the function with

```
bep(15000,50,300)
```

everything works as it should and I get a nice plot.
When I change the function in my while loop to

```
x <- x + 0.01
```

The function runs without ending. I checked with a print(x) argument in the loop and it just goes over the break even point of 60…
The loop goes on forever.
Is there a way of solving the two linear equations like

```
Kf + kv * x = U * x
```

Using the solve() function so I don't have to use the while loop? The solve function should calculate x (all the other variables are passed as arguments to the function).
I tried solve but couldn't figure it out.
Thank's for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that as you index `x` it might not exactly solve the equation. An alternative to `Kf + kv*x = p*x` is to explicitly solve for `x` as `x = Kf/(p - kv)`. This avoids iterations and should be faster.

```
bep <- function(Kf,kv,p){
  x <- Kf/(p-kv)
  bep <- x
  print(bep)
  print(p*bep)
  x <- seq(0, 100, by=10)
  K <- Kf + kv * x
  U <- p * x
  plot(x, K, type="l", col="red", ylim=c(0,20000))
  lines(x, U, col="green")
  points(bep, Kf+kv*bep)
  segments(x0 = 0, y0 = p * bep, x1 = bep, y1= p * bep, lty = "dotted")
  segments(x0 = bep, y0 = 0, x1 = bep, y1 = p * bep, lty = "dotted")
}

bep(15000,50,300)
```

Comment: Thank's! Sometimes the obvious is so near…